# Laravel subquery (select) in DB:Raw

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, join, group-by

I am trying to display the user's favorite articles
And I want for each article the number of users who put it in their favorites

I tried using this code:

```
$result = $result->join('favorite_clothes', 'favorite_clothes.clothe_id', '=', 'clothes.id');
$result = $result->Where('favorite_clothes.user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
$result = $result
->groupBy('clothes.id')
->get(["clothes.id", DB::raw("count(favorite_clothes.id) as favorite_count"), "clothes.name"])
->toArray();
```

but in this case the `favorite_count` always one (1).
I think I can resolve it using subquery in `DB:raw()` like

```
DB::raw("SELECT count(favorite_clothes.id) as favorite_count from favorite_clothes where favorite_clothes.clothe_id = clothes.id")
```

But this does not work.
is there any other way ?
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fond a solution ,I had to join the same table twice.
**first**: to get current user favorite products only,
**second**: to get users who put it in their favorites.

```
$result = $result->join('favorite_clothes', 'favorite_clothes.clothe_id', '=', 'clothes.id');
$result = $result->join('favorite_clothes as fc_for_count', 'favorite_clothes.clothe_id', '=', 'clothes.id');
$result = $result->Where('favorite_clothes.user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
$result = $result->groupBy('clothes.id')
                 ->get(["clothes.id", DB::raw("count(fc_for_count.id) as favorite_count"), "clothes.name"])
                 ->toArray();
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I want for each article the number of users who put it in their favorites

I think that you want:

```
select clothe_id , count(*) no_users
from favorite_clothes
group by clothe_id
```

If you want to display the name of the clothe rather than its id, then:

```
select c.name, count(*) no_users
from favorite_clothes fc
inner join clothes c on c.id = fc.clothe_id
group by fc.clothe_id, c.name
```

Comment: I have a query that can solve the problem but am looking for a way to put it in the **laravel** code above.
`SELECT count(favorite_clothes.id) as favorite_count from favorite_clothes where favorite_clothes.clothe_id = clothes.id`

Comment: @Nourein: this is not valid SQL (as a starter, there is no `from` clause). I can't tell you how to translate my query to lavarel though - however you should be able to run it as a raw query.

Comment: Typo, modified.
but still not working,
because `DB:raw()` Does not accept subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

if you have relations on your models:

```
$user = User::find(1);

foreach($user->favoriteClothes As $favoriteClothe)
{
 $numberOfFavoriteWithSameClothe = $favoriteClothe->users->count();
}
```

**Update for short query**

```
User::find(1)->with(['favoriteClothes' => function ($q) {
    $q->withCount('users');
}])->find();
```

Comment: this is a solution, but I'm trying to make every thing in one query, u know complexity, excution time .. etc.

Comment: Is this help to you?